# Powerbuilder randomly checking and unchecking Extend Ancestor Script

Tags: inheritance, powerbuilder

Hierarchy,for context:

**window**
‎‎
‎‎v

**w_base**

‎‎v

**w_mywin1** -has-> wf_func()
‎‎
‎‎v

**w_mywin2** -> wf_func()

- wf_func() Being a object function
- w_base    Being a window
- EAS       Being Extend Ancestor Script

When I add code to wf_func in the inherited window EAS is enabled and checked, but when I test it, the ancestor doesn't run, I check wf_func() again and EAS is unchecked and disabled.

I have disabled EAS on a CommandButton in the window, when I enable it and go to wf_func() EAS is enabled. This is not consistent. Am I doing something wrong that causes PB(19 R3) to freak out?

I know and have fixed it with a super:: call, at first, but the window seems to have other inheritance problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are not extended from the ancestor, events are.  If you modify a descendent function then only the code there will execute unless you explicitly call the ancestor function.

Comment: Thanks! could sworn they did, but oh well. When editing and after saving the EAS is enabled and checked ‍♂️, I fixed it temporarily by doing a super:: call but I guess that's permanent now. Kinda new to PB believe it or not.